# How to find out the array dimensions of functions in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I can find information about parameters from the `information_schema.parameters` (or `pg_proc`), but I can't work out how to find the dimensions of an array parameter?

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.one_dim(arr TEXT[]) RETURNS TEXT[]
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT arr;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.two_dim(arr TEXT[][]) RETURNS TEXT[][]
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT arr;
$$;

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.parameters p
WHERE p.parameter_name = 'arr';
```

Returns:

```
"specific_catalog","specific_schema","specific_name","ordinal_position","parameter_mode","is_result","as_locator","parameter_name","data_type","character_maximum_length","character_octet_length","character_set_catalog","character_set_schema","character_set_name","collation_catalog","collation_schema","collation_name","numeric_precision","numeric_precision_radix","numeric_scale","datetime_precision","interval_type","interval_precision","udt_catalog","udt_schema","udt_name","scope_catalog","scope_schema","scope_name","maximum_cardinality","dtd_identifier","parameter_default"
"postgres","pg_temp_10","one_dim_119648",1,"IN","NO","NO","arr","ARRAY",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"postgres","pg_catalog","_text",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"1",NULL
"postgres","pg_temp_10","two_dim_119649",1,"IN","NO","NO","arr","ARRAY",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"postgres","pg_catalog","_text",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"1",NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The dimensions are part of the value, not the type. PostgreSQL arrays are multi-dimensional.

```
=> SELECT pg_typeof(NULL::text[]);
┌───────────┐
│ pg_typeof │
├───────────┤
│ text[]    │
└───────────┘
(1 row)

=> SELECT pg_typeof(NULL::text[][]);
┌───────────┐
│ pg_typeof │
├───────────┤
│ text[]    │
└───────────┘
(1 row)
```